# How get zsh prompt of form: [working-directory] # under macOS

Tags: zsh, command-prompt

In macOS Catalina (10.15.6), I want to use zsh for Terminal sessions. Formerly I had been using the default bash. For bash, I had a .profile containing the line

```
export PS1="[\u@\h:\w]$ "
```

which gave a prompt of the form:

```
[me@myhost:current-dir]$
```

I want something similar for zsh, but without the user-name@host-name prefix and with # instead of $ for the actual prompt.

In a zsh Terminal session, the command

```
PROMPT='[%/]%% '
```

gives the expected prompt, with the current directory enclosed in square brackets.

Of course I don't want to enter that manually each time. Instead, I want to set this in .zprofile. So in .zprofile I included the line

```
export PROMPT='[%/]%% '
```

However, that does not work as expected -- the prompt now has the form:

```
me@myhost current-dir %
```

**Question:** How can I get the zsh prompt to have the desired form as follows?

```
[current-dir] %
```

Comment: It does not make much sense do put this into `.zprofile`, because you want to have the settings in **every interactive** zsh, don't you? I would put them into `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following export to **~/.zshrc**, otherwise it won't work.

```
 export PROMPT='[%1~] %%'
```

That will give you the following, my directory name is `test-workflow-branch-only`

```
[test-workflow-branch-only] %
```

NOTE: This will give you `[~] %` when in `~/` directory so don't be alarmed when you see that

**UPDATE** - per comment questions

We add it to ~/.zshrc as this file gets sourced in all interactive shell configurations. The file ~/.zprofile are for commands that we want to execute when we log in, therefore a non-login shell won't source this file.

Comment: To clarify:  that will *not* work if the line is placed in .zprofile instead of in .zshrc?

Comment: @murray correct, you have to put the line in ~/.zshrc file as this file gets sourced in all interactive shell configurations. The file ~/.zprofile are for commands that you want to execute when you log in, therefore a non-login shell won't source this file.

Comment: @murray : It would work if your shell happens to be an interactive login shell, but it would not work if your shell is an interactive non-login shell. Plus, if your shell happens to be a non-interactive login shell, the settings would be applied, but be pointless.

Comment: @user1934428: Sorry, I don't understand the distinctin between "interactive login shell" and "interactive non-login shell" here. I'm using macOS, and the prompt is relevant only when I open Terminal.app.

Comment: Zsh considers itself as login shell, if it is either invoked using the `-L` option, or by a name which starts with a dash (`-`). Since you only need a special behaviour for an interactive shell, I would use a solution where you don't need to care whether you have a login- or non-login-Shell.

Comment: @user1934428: Sorry, still don't understand how/when one might use zsh (or any other shell) as a login shell except by issuing a command from inside an already-open Terminal.app session. Where would one do that and what form would the command take that includes the `-L` or `-`?

Comment: @murray here is a resource with a deep explanation on the matter. But I would say feel free to create another question so that the difference in shells response is also kept in stack overflow. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html

Comment: @murray : Aside from the fact that you can define your default login shell freely (using `chsh`), each reasonable terminal app I am aware of, allows you to specify the command to be run in a new terminal. Hence, you can choose whether to run a bash or a zsh or whatever in a new terminal, and you can also specify whether you want to run this as a login shell. It is your terminal program, so you configure it the way you like it.

Comment: @EdwardRomero that comment with a link to the docs is good, if you add it to your answer I'll give you an upvote on the answer too

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for info from Edward Romero. My critique of answer is that it contains four wasted characters, '[',']',' ','%'. Using instead PROMPT='%d>' yields the nice clear absolute path, something like this:

```
/Users/myuser/test-workflow-branch-only>
```

In any case, nice to get this headache behind me, and begin reaping the wonderful benefits of using zsh, whatever they may be.